# why do i keep getting a syntax error in this code

Tags: postgresql

I keep getting a syntax error for CASE on the below code. is it because my code is wrong ?

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, manager_id
FROM employees,
CASE WHEN manager_id='null' THEN text 'unmanaged'
END 
FROM employees
```

Comment: yes, you have errors, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't have a `CASE` in the `FROM` clause. Did you mean to put that in the `SELECT` list?

Comment: [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you have two `FROM` clauses in your query. So something like this should work:

```
  SELECT last_name,
         first_name,
         manager_id,
         CASE WHEN manager_id IS NULL THEN 'unmanaged'::text ELSE 'managed'::text END
  FROM employees
```

Furthermore, notice this from the PostgreSQL Documentation:

> Do not write expression = NULL because NULL is not "equal to" NULL. (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal.) This behavior conforms to the SQL standard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a little here, but I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT last_name, 
  first_name, 
  manager_id, 
  CASE WHEN manager_id='null' THEN 'unmanaged' ELSE 'managed' END 
FROM employees
```

...Or possibly this:

```
SELECT last_name, 
  first_name, 
  COALESCE(manager_id, 'unmanaged')
FROM employees
```

Comment: "Create a query which lists all employees with their last names, first names and
manager IDs. For those employees who do not have a manager / supervisor, the
manager_id column shall indicate the text ‘unmanaged’." it is form this question that i was trying to generate the query